# C++ Generic Addition Method

Tags: c++, generics

I have struct like this

```
template <typename T>
struct container
{
T norm() const
    {
        T sum = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sum += value[i];
        }
        return sum;
    };
private:
    T *value{nullptr};
    unsigned int length{0};
};
```

I have a norm() method that adds all the values from the "value".
I need to write this method so that it can add numbers and concatenate strings, characters.
The question is that I do not understand how to determine what type of variable is passed and how to set the type for the "sum"
I thought to determine the size of the first element and determine the type of the variable from it, but maybe there is a better method?

Comment: You mean to do this: `T sum = {};`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you explain how it works?

Comment: Also, if you want to be be more flexible, and the type `T` has a different way to concatenate other than `+=`, you could pass as a template argument an additional "helper" function that will do the concatenation.  This is similar to how `std::sort` has an additional argument that gives the sort criteria, other than `<`.  Or just have two functions, one that works with `+=` and another that works with a user-defined "add" function.

Comment: Now that I look at your code more closely, you may have also used `T sum = std::accumulate(value, value + length, T{}, std::plus<T>()); return sum;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize a `T`, the way to do that in the template function is to use the brace-initializer:

`T sum = {};`

This will initialize sum to whatever the type `T` would be equal to if you default construct (for classes such as `std::string`) or value-initialize (for types such as `int`, `double`, etc.).  For integer types, `double`, `float`, it is 0.  For `std::string` it would be an empty string, etc.

---

After taking another look at your `norm` function, the following should also give the same results (not tested):

```
template <typename T>
T norm() const
{
    return std::accumulate(value, value + length, T{}, std::plus<T>());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer to reflect this.